# ListView items' borders change color (like temporally highlighted or flicker) when clicked?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Each item in the ListView consists of a CardView that has a TextView inside.

This is not a bug this is just the normal way android listview shows that the item was clicked (like highlighting it till you release touch). (u have seen it right?)

But i dont want this functionality as I handle the clicks manually. How to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove selector color try this(add transparent list selector color):

```
<ListView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

To change it, try below:

First create a selector XML (listitem_selector.xml) file in your drawable folder,

```
<!-- pressed state-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected_state" android:state_pressed="true"/>

<!-- focused state-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected_state" android:state_focused="true"/>

<!-- default state-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_state"/>
```

Then in your Layout XML, Find your listview and add

```
<ListView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_selector"
/>
```

Or you can add selector for your row items.
For that, you need to set background drawable of the row layout as

```
android:background="@drawable/listitem_selector"
```

and you need to set your listview's list selector like that:

```
<ListView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

Comment: In my case simply ~android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"~ line was sufficiant as I only needed to remove. Thank you works perfect.